# Is there a standard notation for the following function?

Tags: notation

In machine learning the following function is used pretty often:
$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
g(x) & x > 0\\ 
h(x) & x \leqslant 0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Is there a standard more compact notation? Something like $\varsigma \left ( g(x), h(x) \right )$.

Comment: Is $$f(x) = g(x)\mathbf{1}_{(0,\infty)}(x) + h(x)\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,0]}(x)$$ compact enough?

Comment: $f=Hh+(1-H)g$, where $H$ is the Heaviside function.

Comment: @ClementC. never saw such notation but it is compact enough for me. Also I learned something I have never seen before. Thank you

Comment: I don’t think that one should expect that there will be a standard notation for any particular function, beyond the definition. After all, there isn’t even a standard notation for the $n$-th power function. (We say, “$x^n$”, but that’s just stating the value at a general $x$.)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, no. The closest you can get is writing 
$$
f(x) = \mathbb{1}_{x\leq 0}(x) \cdot h(x) + \mathbb{1}_{x>0}(x)\cdot g(x)
$$
where $1_A: A \to \{0, 1\}$ is the [Indicator function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)

Comment: There is an abuse of notation: $\mathbb{1}_{(0,\infty)}(x)$ or $\mathbb{1}_{\{x>0\}}$, not a mix of both...